# set default scanner for skanlite

Tags: scanner, sane

Every time I run skanlite it searches for all available scanners, and presents me with a list. I want to set my Brother_MFC_L2710DW_series as the default scanner so I don't have to go through this process every time.

The skanlite handbook
https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/skanlite/skanlite/using-skanlite.html
says to use `skanlite -d [device name]` in a terminal but that just brings up the scanner search box, it doesn't permanently set the default scanner.

The command I ran:`skanlite -d Brother_MFC_L2710DW_series`

`lpstat -a` shows:

```
Brother_MFC_L2710DW_series accepting requests since Sun 02 Jan 2022 12:55:07 AM IST
HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_ accepting requests since Sun 02 Jan 2022 12:55:07 AM IST
```

`lpstat -s` shows:

```
system default destination: Brother_MFC_L2710DW_series
device for Brother_MFC_L2710DW_series: implicitclass://Brother_MFC_L2710DW_series/
device for HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_: implicitclass://HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_/
```

I am running Kubuntu 21.10

Comment: Pls add the following information to your question - The full command that you are using when you run `skanlite -d` and the output of `lpstat -a` and `lpstat -s`

Comment: added the requested info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

The scanners being searched for are determined by the contents of `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` and `/etc/sane.d/dll.d/`. Deleting or commenting out entries will speed up the search process and prevent a scanner being displayed.

This may suit you if you are concerned only with using the Brother scanner.

Comment: I looked in those files and didn't see an entry for brother

Comment: Installation the Brother scanning package should add `brother4` to dll.conf. **Without it, scanning with your device cannot take place**. Edit the file to add it.

Comment: I installed brscan4-0.4.10-1.amd64.deb and it added brother4, like you said. And it did speed up the search process immensely. Interestingly, after deleting all other entries from dll.conf,, it still finds my HP printer/scanner (which I don't want to use) but that's okay. And it found my Brother printer MFC even before I installed the driver for it. I think this is a capability of KDE Plasma.   On Xfce desktops, I remember struggling to get the scanner recognized.

Comment: The HP printer/scanner may be dealt with in `/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hplip`. A much neater solution is `apt purge libsane-hpaio`.

Comment: I did "apt purge libsane-hpaio" and my HP printer/scanner still shows up, but now it is second in the list, so it is really fast and easy to just select my Brother printer/scanner and get on with things.